# Unable to create DataPropertyAssertion with OWL API

Tags: owl-api

CODE:

```
OWLDataProperty prop = factory.getOWLDataProperty(IRI.create(getOntologyIRI()  + "#" +  owlDataProp));
OWLNamedIndividual ind = factory.getOWLNamedIndividual(IRI.create(getOntologyIRI()  + "#" +  owlNamedIndividual));
OWLLiteral lit = factory.getOWLLiteral(val);

OWLDataPropertyAssertionAxiom axiom = factory.getOWLDataPropertyAssertionAxiom(prop, ind, lit);
if(manager.addAxiom(this.ontology, axiom) == ChangeApplied.SUCCESSFULLY)
    return saveOntology();
return false;
```

creates:

[image: Protege SS]
and
[image]

But expected result is (manually created):

[image: Protege SS2]

I try to create OWLNegativeDataPropertyAssertionAxiom and it works fine. Also if I create getOWLNegativeDataPropertyAssertionAxiom first and then create OWLDataPropertyAssertionAxiom - it works.

OWLAPI: **owlapi-distribution-4.1.4.jar**

**EDIT:**

Created ontologies:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns="gunkoFB.owl#"
 xml:base="gunkoFB.owl"
 xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
 xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
 xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
 xmlns:gunkoFB="gunkoFB.owl#"
 xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
<owl:Ontology rdf:about="gunkoFB.owl"/>

<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="gunkoFB.owl#hasFirstName"/>

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="gunkoFB.owl#Michal_Joštiak">
    <hasFirstName rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Michal</hasFirstName>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<rdf:RDF xmlns="gunkoFB.owl#"
 xml:base="gunkoFB.owl"
 xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
 xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
 xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
 xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
<owl:Ontology rdf:about="gunkoFB.owl"/>

<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="gunkoFB.owl#hasFirstName"/>

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="gunkoFB.owl#Michal_Joštiak"/>
<rdf:Description>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NegativePropertyAssertion"/>
    <owl:sourceIndividual rdf:resource="gunkoFB.owl#Michal_Joštiak"/>
    <owl:assertionProperty rdf:resource="gunkoFB.owl#hasFirstName"/>
    <owl:targetValue rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Michal</owl:targetValue>
</rdf:Description>
```

Comment: This case is when I save ontology as RDF/XML. Maybe its just Protege fail. When I save ontology as OWL/XML its OK again.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like missed declarations. Can you try this with 4.2.5? There have been bugs fixed in this area in the last few versions.

Edit: after checking the code in the [OWLAPI issue tracker](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/issues/557), it turns out the issue is the ontology IRI, which needs to be absolute. The relative IRI means that, when saving to a file, the file location is used to disambiguate the declaration IRIs; however this is not done uniformly, causing missed declarations - which is the root issue.

As a workaround while the bug is fixed, use absolute IRIs for the ontology IRI.

Comment: I have added created ontologies, they used entirely different notation.